# "gzserver: symbol lookup error" (not ignition problem) when launching Gazebo v9.19 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I try to launch the Gazebo from terminal;

gazebo --verbose

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.19.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.19.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.

[Msg] Waiting for master.

[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345

[Msg] Publicized address: 10.76.137.168

[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345

[Msg] Publicized address: 10.76.137.168

[Msg] Loading world file [/usr/share/gazebo-9/worlds/empty.world]

gzserver: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo.so.9: undefined symbol: _ZN3sdf28recursiveSameTypeUniqueNamesESt10shared_ptrINS_7ElementEE

this error occurs. I really can't understand what is the meaning of this "undefined symbol". I don't now how can I fix this problem. (Also I'm using ROS melodic but I just can't launch Gazebo as you can see above so I don't know is it important.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27602/%22gzserver:-symbol-lookup-error%22-(not-ignition-problem)-when-launching-gazebo-v9.19-in-ubuntu-18.04/) by [Mustafa](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/63053/mustafa/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2021-11-29**:
This looks like a version mismatch between gazebo and libsdformat. Can you tell me which version of libsdformat you have installed? You can do this with `apt-cache policy libsdformat6`

**Comment by [Mustafa](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/63053/mustafa/) on 2021-12-06**:
@azeey installed version of libsdformat6 is 6.2.0.1~bionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 9.19 needs `libsdformat6` >= 6.3.0. It should have been installed when installing/upgrading
the `gazebo9` package, but it looks like your system still has 6.2.0. Upgrading or reinstalling `libsdformat6` should resolve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2021-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mustafa](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/63053/mustafa/) on 2021-12-07**:
Yes, it solved my problem thank you.